# align Lightning modal header text to left

Tags: css, slds

want to align lightning modal text header to extreme left (Styling issue)

[image]

just want to align terms and condition text to left side but not shifting 
even after applying css align: left

modal.cmp

```
<div class="demo-only" style="height: 640px;">
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" onclick="{!c.hideExampleModal}" title="Close">
                     <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="medium" variant="bare"/>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate"><b>{!$Label.c.TermsAndCondition}</b>

                </h2>


            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="block1">
                  {!$Label.c.TermsAndConditions_Content}
            </div>
            <footer class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                <lightning:button class="Buttongry" variant="neutral" label="{!$Label.c.Print}" onclick="{!c.performprint}"/>
                <lightning:button class="Buttonblue" variant="brand" label="{!$Label.c.IAgree}" onclick="{!c.AgreeBtn}"/>

            </footer>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</div>
```

modal.css

```
  .THIS .slds-modal__header  {
    background: #f2f9fc;
  }
  .THIS .slds-modal__container {
    margin: 0 auto;
     width: 40%;    
  }
  .THIS .slds-modal__footer{
      background-color: white; }

 @media print {
  .THIS .slds-modal__footer {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code over here?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're ignoring SLDS if you make changes like this--your application won't *quite* look like the rest of Salesforce. If your goal is to have your component *look* like Salesforce, you should not be trying to change alignments/colors/etc from the prescribed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below css style

```
.THIS .slds-hyphenate  {
  text-align: left!important;
}
```

Comment: .THIS .slds-hyphenate  {
 float: left;
}                                  
this also worked for me but thanks though